# дубликат ID на Java или Ajax без разницы на чем

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ребята, у меня есть цена- цифра которая формируется js скриптом в зависимости от того что выбрал пользователь и меняется на лету вот в такой html строке-

```
<div class="right">
                Цена Услуги
                <span id="total_bet_amount"><b></b></span> 
             </div>
```

Это стоит вверху сайта, НО я бы хотел чтобы эта же цена отображалась еще и внизу, если я просто вниз вставляю вот такую строку-

```
<p><strong>Цена: </strong><span id="total_bet_amount"><b></b></span>
```

то естественно не работает, так как получается два одинаковых id на одой странице)
так вот есть ли какая нибудь "фитча" типа дубликата?
ну то есть чтобы внизу стояла какая то переменная которая просто зеркалит то значение которое принимает id="total_bet_amount" в текущий момент.

Ну грубо говоря вот так я хочу вставить вниз страницы-

```
<p><strong>Цена: </strong><span Duplicate id="total_bet_amount"><b></b></span>
```

есть что то подобное?

Comment: Есть же функция, которая добавляет значение в `total_bet_amount`... что мешает на следующей строчке то же самое сделать и для другого id ?

Comment: то есть всю функцию скопировать для еще одного id? или можно как то проще, допустим чтобы функция сразу для двух работала? у меня во всей функции ID только один раз фигурирует, вот в этой строке const sumNode = document.querySelector('#total_bet_amount > b');   может можно в нее же сразу и второй ID добавить чтобы не дублировать километровый код целиком?

Comment: Километровый код можно вынести в отдельную функцию и использовать её для нужный айдишников. Или искать по классу, пробежаться по найденным элементам и выполнить функцию

Comment: продублировать скрипт второй раз но с новым id не получилось) так как в скрипте чек боксы и когда пользователь их дергает то не смотря на два разных ID все равно сумма меняется только в каком то одном....

Comment: <script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
       var price0 = "{{$service->price}}";
       var price1 = "{{$service->dop1_price}}";
              
const sumNode = document.querySelector('#total_bet_amount > b');
sumNode.innerText = price0;
document.querySelectorAll('.options').forEach((opt, i) => {
    opt.value = eval('price' + (i+1));
    opt.checked = false;
  opt.onchange = function() {
    if (opt.checked) sumNode.innerText = +sumNode.innerText + +opt.value;
    else sumNode.innerText = +sumNode.innerText - +opt.value
  }
});
});
</script>

Comment: `const sumNode = document.querySelector('#total_bet_amount > b'); sumNode.innerText = price0;` заменить на → `const sumNode = document.querySelector('#total_bet_amount > b'); const sumNode_2 = document.querySelector('#другое_id > b'); sumNode.innerText = sumNode_2.innerText = price0;`

Answer (score 0):

спасибо ОПТИМУС ПРАЙМ за наводку на мысль) что можно просто скриптом редактирвать сразу двай айдишника а не мудохаться потом с клонами_)
в итоге просто вот такое изменение в скрипте ява решили вопрос-

```
const sumNodes = [];
```

sumNodes.push(document.querySelector('#total_bet_amount > b'));
sumNodes.push(document.querySelector('#total_bet_amount2 > b'));